# How to trigger self hover on child element

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `divs`one inside other. When I mouse over on most inner div, I want to trigger `:hover` but it's not working as expected.

How can I solve this issue? Live demo [here](http://codepen.io/vaibhavkadam/pen/LpEZZw)

HTML goes like this.

```
<div class="orange">
  <div class="white">
     <div class="green">
       <div class="blue">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS goes like this.

```
.orange:hover .blue {
    background-color: orange;
}
.white:hover .blue {
    background-color: white;
}
.green:hover .blue {
    background-color: green;
}
.blue:hover{
    background-color:blue;
}
.orange
{
  position:fixed; top:0; left:0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:orange;
}
.white
{
  top: 50px; margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:white;
}
.green
{
  top: 50px; margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:green;
}
.blue
{
  top: 50px; margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused what your desired behaviour is, but I edited your fiddle to be what I think you want:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOEXMj. This solution does not require you to change your html.

Comment: This works, But I was really trying to solve a bigger issue, preventing default using css.

Comment: @daniman Can you put this in answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `!important` will solved your problem. but using `!important` how much is flexible for you, it depends on your code
See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/gx8um0zf/)

```css
.orange:hover .blue {
    background-color: orange;
}
.white:hover .blue {
    background-color: white;
}
.green:hover .blue {
    background-color: green;
}
.blue:hover{
background-color:blue !important;
}
.orange
{
  position:fixed; top:0; left:0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:orange;
}
.white
{
  top: 50px; margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:white;
}
.green
{
  top: 50px; margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:green;
}
.blue
{
  top: 50px; margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="chbg('red')" class="orange">
  <div class="white">
     <div class="green">
       <div class="blue">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another class that is affected in the inner most ring.  It happens that way because your classes are nested.

## CSS

```
.orange:hover .inner {
  background-color: orange;
}

.white:hover .inner {
  background-color: white;
}

.green:hover .inner {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue:hover .inner {
  background-color: blue;
}


.inner {
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div onmouseover="chbg('red')" class="orange">
  <div class="white">
    <div class="green">
      <div class="blue">
        <div class="inner">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Leave the rest of your color classes as they are.